# How to download a text file from amazon s3 using Pentaho?

Tags: amazon-s3, pentaho, pdi

Am new in pentaho, so please help me in following doubt. I upload a text file in s3 bucket. I need to download that file to my local machine through Pentaho transformation. Please any one give the explanation about it.

Comment: Are these files encrypted?

Comment: no, its just a text file.

Comment: Did you try S3 input step?

Comment: yes i tried. but get an error message like this. "There was an error while trying to get a list of the variables s3 files (keys)": s3 GET failed for '/'

Comment: Do you know shell scripting? I can give you a basic idea of how to do it using a shell script.

Comment: Okay give me. Is it possible by using aws cp command.?

Comment: Thanks broh for your comments.. i find out the soluton. here posted my solutins.    aws s3 cp --recursive s3://s3 bucket path/  local path